# php in a javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, foreach

The folowing code should show me the results of the selected ID :

```
<form id="<?= $blog_id ?>" method="post" action="show.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="<?= $blog_id ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="blog_title" value="<?= $blog_title ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="blog_date" value="<?= $blog_date ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="blog_content" value="<?= $blog_content ?>">

    Click <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('<?= $blog_id ?>').submit();">here</a> to see (<?= count($blog_comments) ?>) comments.
</form>
```

But when i click the link, it does nothing (Does not lead me to show.php).
However, if i change `onclick="document.getElementById('<?= $blog_id ?>')` To `onclick="document.getElementById('test')` (And also the other id).
It leads me to show.php, but shows me the highest ID.
Why do i need the id to be a variable? because it is in a loop, and when i click the link, i want to get the correct information from the selected id.

I looked at my console (inspect element), and it says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function
```

However i don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Instead of using inline JS, can you bind event handlers dynamically? E.g. using `obj.addEventListener()`.

Comment: based on javascript, i'm very inexperienced, can you please tell more about obj.addEventListener()

Comment: try to use "" rather than ''    Click <a href="#" onclick='document.getElementById("<?= $blog_id ?>").submit();'>here</a> to see (<?= count($blog_comments) ?>) comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO is not good idea to set ID of form to numer:

first standards:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

but, maybe in Your case is problem in duplicate ID in code. Maybe You have more that one element with this ID ?

try this:

```
    <form id="form_<?= $blog_id ?>" method="post" action="show.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="<?= $blog_id ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="blog_title" value="<?= $blog_title ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="blog_date" value="<?= $blog_date ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="blog_content" value="<?= $blog_content ?>">

        Click <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form_<?= $blog_id ?>').submit();">here</a> to see (<?= count($blog_comments) ?>) comments.
    </form>
```

Comment: Those are standards for HTML4. HTML5 is now more permissive and does allow you to set number-only ids, even though I agree it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple test and it this works

**Maybe ryrysz is right.**

test.php

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<11; $i++): ?>
<?php  
    $blog_id =$i;
    $blog_title = 'abc'.$i;
    $blog_date = '11-02-2012';
    $blog_content = 'dsfdsfdfsdfsdfs'.$i;
    $blog_comments[] = '';
?>
<form id="<?= $blog_id ?>" method="post" action="show.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="<?= $blog_id ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="blog_title" value="<?= $blog_title ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="blog_date" value="<?= $blog_date ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="blog_content" value="<?= $blog_content ?>">

    Click <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('<?= $blog_id ?>').submit();">here</a> to see (<?= count($blog_comments) ?>) comments.
</form>
<?php endfor ?>
```

show.php

```
<?php
print_R($_POST);
```